# How to run my JavaScript functions through states in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my JavaScript code, I am trying to use this code in my react component and although this works, but when reload all the things are gone. I want to put all this code into react state to make it easier for me to run this app.

**JavaScript Code**

```
const 
    var currentSlide = 0;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide")
    const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');

    const init = (n) => {
        slides.forEach((slide) => {
        


          slide.style.display = "none"
          dots.forEach((dot) => {
            dot.classList.remove("active");
          })
        })
        slides[n].style.display = "block";
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
      }
      document.addEventListener("onload", init(currentSlide));


      const next = () => {
  


        currentSlide >= slides.length - 1 ? currentSlide = 0 : currentSlide++
        init(currentSlide)
      }
      
      const prev = () => {


        currentSlide <= 0 ? currentSlide = slides.length - 1 : currentSlide--
        init(currentSlide)
      }
      document.querySelector(".scroll-button").addEventListener('click', next)
      document.querySelector(".scroll-button-left").addEventListener('click', prev);

      setInterval(() => {


          next();
      }, 5000);

      dots.forEach((dot, index) => {


        dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
     
          init(index)
          currentSlide = index;
        })
      })
```

And here is the simple code on which I want this functionality to be applied on.

```
        <div className="slide-container">
            {/* Images for scrolling */}
        <div class="slide fade" style={initial}>
        <img src={img1} alt='' />
      </div>
        <div class="slide fade">
        <img src={img2} alt='' />
      </div>
        <div class="slide fade">
        <img src={img3} alt='' />
      </div>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right scroll-button"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right scroll-button-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div className="scroll-portion">

        <div className="first-button">
                <button>Enroll Now</button>
                </div>
                {/* Left and Rigth Button for slider  */}


{/* Dots Container */}
        <div class="dots-container">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you reload the page your previous states are gone?

Comment: @mamady Yes, when I reload all the page is empty. I want to put all my JavaScript logic through react. How can I do this? Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: I think you're mistaking logic with data. Your logic is already in your components. If you want the data (react states or whatever) created by the client to stay after reload, use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). But man, there is so much wrong with your code that I recommend learning react and js first.